# Check SP group permissions in Designer Workflow

Tags: workflow, permissions, designer-workflow, groups

Is it possible to check if a particular user is in a Site Group from within a SharePoint Designer Workflow?

For example, if the status column of my list item is set to "Approved", it will kick off a workflow that can check if the person that last modified is in the "Supervisors" group, since only Supervisors should be able to approve items. Do workflow conditions have this kind of group security functionality?

Answer (score 1):

The "Modified by Specific Person" condition will allow you to compare to a group as well as people. So you can have an if condition to test the status, with a nested if-else condition to test for the group.

Comment: Sorry to have to go back to this one, but I tested the "Modified By Specific Person" and the condition fails even though I am in the group that I am checking. Does this condition actually check specific users within the group as well?